# Reproducing R Art/ Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to reproduce [this graph](https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/137-spring-shapes-data-art/). There parameter "line = element_blank()" appears twice; I commented one occurrence.  When one runs the code (with current versions of the packages, in RStudio) one gets the error message: "Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (900): colour, alpha."

My ggplot experience is limited. I could not fix the error by following solutions to similar errors. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The provided code has an extra color aesthetic in your ggplot command.  If you remove the color = element_blank() from the geom_area command I believe your plot will render.